# OpenMP running time

Tags: c++, openmp

I am running some parallel work using OpenMP, but find that speedup does not scale well. I then found that as the number of threads increases, the time for doing the same amount of work increases as well. Here is the example:

```
void fillingVec(vector<int>& vec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        vec.push_back(i);
}

int main() {
    const int num_thread = omp_get_max_threads();
    vector<int> vec;
    double start;
    #pragma omp parallel \
    private(vec)
    {
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        start = omp_get_wtime();
        fillingVec(vec);
    }
    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Elasped time = %f sec\n", end - start);

    return 0;
}
```

Since I run same work for each thread, I expect the running time is similar for different thread numbers. However, as I tested the program, the running time seems increases linearly as the number of thread increases. Here are the results:

```
#     time
1     0.004387
4     0.009015
16    0.034197
32    0.230581
```

Can someone explain why it is the case? Is it simply due to the overhead of OpenMP?

Comment: What hardware is it (how many cores)? I would suggest to simplify benchamrk (leaving empty loop only). And also increasing runtime a bit. I've tried Your example (a bit modified), and it seems to be some overhead, but not sure if it is hardware or software related.

Comment: You can also get some insight by running N processes at the same time (the same program would be ok, just run N processes with single thread).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the time increase is due to memory allocation overhead. Try reserving the space for the vector (with `vec.reserve(1000000);`) before filling it with data.

Also, the way you measure time is strange and has a data race, because each thread in the parallel region writes into the shared `start` variable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But even I reserve the vector beforehand, the running time still grows linearly. I also change to other instructions, but still the problem remains.